# LinearLayout isn't stretching. Filename collision?

Tags: android, android-layout

Would you mind pointing out the reason why LinearLayout element isn't stretching to match parent element. Is this related to project configuration or class names I use ? I've  noticed that name of the xmlfile might be somehow related to this issue. I'm not joking - a couple of days ago I was testing the same code on different xml file names and it worked differently in terms of LinearLayout stretching. This one  is named "clip.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </LinearLayout>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: The name of the xml file should not affect the way it gets drawn. If you have a definitive (reproduceable) test case in which the name of the file affected the way it was drawn please post it so we can try to see what is going on.

Comment: As I've told - it was couple of days ago, but I just've tried copying this code in a brand-new project and it stretched. So what might be a reason for linearlayout not stretching in my main project?

Comment: I am not certain. A good habit to get to get into is using the 'Clean Project' action within Eclipse when you notice strange errors though. Many times this will clear up anything that doesn't seem to be working properly.

Comment: nice suggestion, but it hasn't helped :(

Answer (score 0):

i see nothing wrong with what you did , but you won't notice a thing in the linearLayout since it doesn't contain anything .

in order to demonstrate it , try setting a background for the linearLayout , for example :

```
android:background="#88ff000000"
```

Comment: I've setup - same stuff. After waking up early I tried to click around  and I have no freaking idea why this is so but when I changed theme from NoTitleBar to default (in graphical layout view) it became as is needed. The funniest part for me is that it hasn't even changed manifest, so I'm absolutely unaware how it helped lol.

Comment: It might be an "Eclipse/Emulator" issue. Haven't tested that bug on real device